# Shell commands work in Terminal but not in Automator service

Tags: command-line, automator

I try to implement these two very simple commands in an Automator service to be run by a keyboard short (takes a screenshot and OCRs it):

```
screencapture -i /tmp/tesseract.png
tesseract /tmp/tesseract.png stdout|tr -d \\f|pbcopy
```

This works great when I execute these commands in the Terminal, but not when I make it an Automator service (sorry this is in German).
[image: Automator window]
I don't understand: Why does it work in the one case and not in the other? Does it have anything to do with tesseract?

Comment: Add the absolute path to tesserac  - `/path/to/tesseract /tmp/tesseract.png stdout|tr -d \\f|pbcopy`

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is it not doing?  Test if tesseract is in your path:  put on the first line the command `echo $PATH`. Post the output.

Comment: Automator might not have access to your clipboard and thus the pbcopy might not do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any *executable* that is not within the `PATH` passed to the **Run Shell Script** *action*, which is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, you must use the *fully qualified pathname* of the *executable*.

In this case, e.g. `/path/to/tesseract`

You should be able to get its *path* in **Terminal** using:

```
which tesseract
```

As `tesseract` is not a default of **macOS**, it may be in `/usr/local/bin/`, however `which tesseract` should report its *fully qualified pathname*.

---

Instead of using the *fully qualified pathname*, or in conjunction with, you can also add a `PATH` *statement* to the top of the **Run Shell Script** *action*, e.g. for a `bash` *shell*:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/"
```

You could also just substitute everything to the right of the `=` sign for what the output in **Terminal**, e.g. `echo $PATH` is. Then the **Run Shell Script** *action* has the same `PATH` as **Terminal**.